# How to pull Data from Youtube CMS using Google AppScipt

Tags: google-apps-script, youtube-javascript-api

I am trying to use the YouTube API to pull in data from you CMS account using Google AppScript.

I can successfully get a token using OAuth2 and I believe I have the proper scopes but I am still getting a 401 error when I try to populate my google spreadsheet with the video ID from the ISRC number.

I made the following changes to the OAuth2 piece to include the proper scope for Youtube CMS according to the youtube partner developer's guide to OAuth2.

```
AUTHORIZE_URL = 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth'; //step 1. we can actually start directly here if that is necessary
var TOKEN_URL = 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token'; //step 2. after we get the callback, go get token
var CLIENT_ID = 'MyClientId';
var CLIENT_SECRET = 'MyClientSecret';
var REDIRECT_URL= ScriptApp.getService().getUrl();
var tokenPropertyName = 'GOOGLE_OAUTH_TOKEN'; 
var baseURLPropertyName = 'GOOGLE_INSTANCE_URL';`enter code here`

function getURLForAuthorization(){
return AUTHORIZE_URL + '?response_type=code&client_id='+CLIENT_ID+'&redirect_uri='+REDIRECT_URL +
'&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtubepartner'+'&access_type=offline'; //added access type from above api guide 
}
```

But I am still receiving an error here:

Request failed for https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/partner/v1/assetSearch?q=USY6C0700704&key=MyAPIKey_simple returned code 401

The requests looks the same as what I am doing in the API Explorer:

GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/partner/v1/assetSearch?q=USY6C0700704&key={YOUR_API_KEY}

So the only think what may be wrong is a problem with my token.

Any help would be greatly appreciated thanks guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you actually done the OAuth flow and stored the access/refresh tokens?

If not, take a look at these two YouTube videos for Apps Script integration with the Data and the Analytics API

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VVhsK5jH6u8
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eumC0nIw-lk

The code for both those videos are available here - 
https://github.com/entaq/GoogleAppsScript/tree/master/YouTube
https://github.com/entaq/GoogleAppsScript/tree/master/IO2013/YouTubeAnalytics

Comment: Arun, Thanks so much for getting back to me!  I have been working with to get this completed and found out that I was not using the correct account with the Content ID service.  I changed this and now I am getting 
Request failed for https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token returned code 400. Truncated server response: { "error" : "unauthorized_client" } (use muteHttpExceptions option to examine full response)
I am using an new client_secret and client_id and made sure they are correct but the error still persists.

Comment: Thanks again - I solved this by putting a link directly to the webapp in my spreadsheet instead of running the getAuth() function.  I still dont know why it did not work conventionally and have not found a lot about the 'unauthorized_client' error.